# Cannot bind property to TreeView nested inside of HeaderTemplate of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, relativesource

I've met really strange issue. I cannot figure out how I can bind property placed in `FooItemsControlViewModel` to View(`FooItemsControl`):

Model:

```
public interface IFolder
{
    string FullPath { get; }
    string FolderLabel { get; }
    List<IFolder> Folders { get; } 
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<IFolder> m_folders;
public ObservableCollection<IFolder> Folders
{
  get { return m_folders; }
  set
      {
        m_folders = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Folders");
      }
}
```

XAML. This `DataTemplate`cwill be used for `<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>` of `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">            
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding FirstName}" >
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
          ...
          <DataTemplate> 
             ...
              <PopUp> 
              <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Folders, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor},  diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" Margin="10">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.FooFolders, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}" DataType="{x:Type toDelete:IFolder}">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding FolderLabel}"/>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      </TreeView>
    ...
    </PopUp>
 </DataTemplate>
 ...
```

I've added Tracing to the Output Window to debug binding:

```
xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

and what I see in Output window is :

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=52875503):
>   Activate with root item FooItemsControl (hash=67071923)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=52875503): 
>   At level 0 using cached accessor for FooItemsControl.DataContext:
>   DependencyProperty(DataContext)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 :
>   BindingExpression (hash=52875503): Replace item at level 0 with
>   FooItemsControl (hash=67071923), using accessor
>   DependencyProperty(DataContext)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 :
>   BindingExpression (hash=52875503): GetValue at level 0 from
>   FooItemsControl (hash=67071923) using DependencyProperty(DataContext):
>   FooItemsControlViewModel (hash=28094463)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=52875503):   At level 1 using cached accessor for FooItemsControlViewModel.Folders:
>   RuntimePropertyInfo(Folders)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=52875503): Replace item at level 1 with FooItemsControlViewModel (hash=28094463), using accessor
>   RuntimePropertyInfo(Folders)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=52875503): GetValue at level 1 from
>   FooItemsControlViewModel (hash=28094463) using
>   RuntimePropertyInfo(Folders):
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 :
>   BindingExpression (hash=52875503): TransferValue - got raw value
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression
>   (hash=52875503): TransferValue - using final value

**And `Folders` property is not shown in `TreeView`. Does anybody know a reason why I cannot see any value in `TreeView`(I saw values earlier)?**

Why do I need `TreeView` inside of `HeaderTemplate`? Let me show an image:
[image]

Comment: Why are you binding the ItemTemplate in the TreeView to a relative source? they already have the datacontext of an item from the TreeView's ItemsSource, so you should either be using that as the binding or a property of that item as the binding.

Comment: @GordonAllocman I've tried your variant, without relative source. Data is not shown. It is very strange issue.

Comment: If you could add some code showing your data models, it might be easier to see what is going wrong. For example show what IFolder is and what properties it has. Also without adding tracing the output window usually gives very useful binding error information by default

Comment: Why do you have a tree in the header of a datagrid?

Comment: @GordonAllocman please, see my updated question

Comment: Isn't that dropdown in the cell itself? The header would be the H

Comment: yeah. there is a `ToggleButton` and `PopUp`. `DataTemplate` is placed inside of `PopUp`.

Comment: Well if that is inside the cell rather than the header you should be using a DataGridTemplateColumn instead of a DataGridTextColumn, otherwise I'm not sure whats up since I've never bound to/templated the header itself